# php database connection errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1040

im hoping someone can help me quickly with a question i have.

As site i have build is occasionally returning with the error

Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (08004/1040): Too many connections in

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in

Now at first i thought this was happening as i hadent closed the connection at the end of each page, now i get the connection like this at the beginning of a page / script

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

and at the very end call

$conn->close();

Also i close any result sets i have open.

Looking at my log files around the time i accessed the site today and saw this error, I accessed about 12 o clock and at first the page wouldnt even load, then it gave me this error. before that one person visted around 11:30 and then 10:30, not exactly heavy traffic.

The host I have gone with is very quiet and there is no way to get in contact with them, and ignoring any support emails, i thought maybe as now i hear they are not very good this could be an issue with a badly set up shared mysql server?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be amazing as i need to sort this out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the MySQL server is being shared by too many accounts, as that error means that the server's `max_connections` setting has been exceeded.  It could be that there are several other high-traffic customers that are taking up the connections (this is a shared MySQL server, I take it?)

I'm fairly sure that PHP automatically closes resources at the end of the request (although it's always best to explicitly close your connections etc. anyway) so I wouldn't think it's your script keeping connections open.

You'll need to keep on at your hosting provider, I'm afraid, or consider moving providers.  Also try to keep a log of when the errors occur and for how long, as you'll need that as evidence if they refuse to acknowledge there's a problem.

You can also refer your provider to this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html.

Comment: thanks for the reply...so you dont think its my fault then! :)

Comment: It doesn't appear so.  If you get in contact with your provider, tell them to examine the results of running "SHOW PROCESSLIST" against the MySQL server - it will show which connections are coming from which servers.

Comment: Also just check your script is not creating persistent connections - make sure your hostname does NOT start with `p:` (unless you want persistent connections but then you really have to check that the connections are being closed/disposed of correctly.)

Comment: host name is just 'localhost', is that what you mean?

host has now got in touch saying they are having load issues...stupid shared server.

I wouldve thought even with a shared server you could specify each database could only consume x amount of connections and not let one site suck them all up!

Comment: Even more worrying, is why are they running both web and database on the same server, especially as it's shared hosting?