# Can't connect to database, too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get following error when I try and connect to my database.

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   in /homez.640/connelho/www/uea/includes/database.php on line 8 Failed
>   to connect to MySQL: (2002) Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I always run the following connect method before I do any SQl queries:

```
public static function connect() {
    require_once("constants.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
```

I always run the following disconnect method after any SQl queries:

```
public static function disconnect($mysqli = NULL, $stmt = NULL) {
    if (isset($mysqli)) {
        $mysqli->close();
    }
    if (isset($stmt)) {
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

I have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499660 and emailed my hosting provider and they have told me to check my scripts "We have 30 MySQL connections as a limit - we cannot adjust this and there is no reason why it should occur if your scripts are run properly". It was working fine for weeks then suddenly stopped connecting. I am the only visitor of the site.

Example as to how my database classes connect and disconnect:

```
public static function county_select() {
    //connect to database
    $mysqli = Database::connect();

    //write sql statement
    $sql = "SELECT id, county FROM Counties ORDER BY country, county ASC";

    //prepared statement, stage 1: prepare
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
        die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
    }

    //prepared statement, stage 2: execute  
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
    }

    //prepared statement, stage 3: bind result
    if (!$stmt->bind_result($id, $county)) {
        die("Binding result failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
    }
    $counties = array();
    //prepared statement, stage 5: fetch    
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $counties[] = array("id" => $id, "county" => $county);
    }
    //disconnect from database
    Database::disconnect($mysqli, $stmt);

    return $counties;
}
```

I haven't been able to connect to my site for a day now. How long until the connections expire? How do I manually disconnect them? I thought PHP automatically closes database connections at the end of a request any way?

Comment: `show processlist;` in the mysql monitor will show you all the active connections. you can then use `kill` to terminate any unwanted connections.

Answer (score 2):

Don't disconnect after the query! Only connect to the database once when the first query occurs. Otherwise you'll try to connect more than necessary, which is more than once.

Always connecting and disconnecting is not a very good idea when looking for performance. And it disables certain functionality: Basically you'll lose anything related to the existing connections, like re-using prepared statements, or accessing LAST_INSERT_ID() in a subsequent query. Keeping the connection alive is important for this.

But your problem usually stems from abusing persistent connections, but I cannot see anything like this here.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've been incredibly stupid. I couldn't connect to the server the other night so I switched my constants I used in the connect method to localhost and then forgot the next day... no wonder I couldn't connect! What a spanner haha. Don't know why I couldn't connect the other night but I can now. Sorry to waste people's time